# Add content and show it immediately in angular with a real server

Tags: angular, http, typescript, http-headers

I have followed the [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial) from angular. And now i am trying to do it in real life with Drupal as a backend.

Everything works fine, all the get, post, put and delete methods are fine... but

**When I create a content, the only way to see it reflected is by updating the page** So my question is: **How can I create content and show it immediately in the angular page.**

I don't want to update the page, I just want to see the new content reflected.

[Edited]

**Some code example**

**Component.html**

```
        <h5>Add Task</h5>
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(taskName.value, taskBody.value)" #heroForm="ngForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Task Name</label>
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
                     required name="name" #taskName>
          </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="body">What to do</label>
          <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="body" name="body" #taskBody>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

Printing the code: this is what I want to update immediately

```
<li *ngFor="let task of tasks" class="d-inline-block col-md-12">
    <a routerLink="/task/{{task.id}}" > {{task.name}}</a>
    <!-- <span class="close big"></span> -->
    <button class="close big" title="delete task"
    (click)="delete(task)">x</button>
</li>
```

**Calling the get tasks function in the class component, to the service.ts**

```
getTasks(): void {
    this.taskService.getTasks()
        .subscribe(Tasks => this.tasks = Tasks);
}
```

**Sending the data from the form to the service**

```
    onSubmit(name: string, body:string): void {
   let task: any = {
       type: [],
       title: [],
       body: []     
    };
    task.type.push({target_id: "task"});
    task.title.push({value: name});
    task.body.push({value: body});

      this.taskService.addTask(task)
        .subscribe(task => {
          this.tasks.push(task);
          // console.log(JSON.stringify(task));    
        });
    }
```

**get task function, in the service**

```
/** GET task by id. Will 404 if id not found */
getTask(id: number): Observable<Task> {
  const url = `${this.taskUrl}/${id}`;
  const returnGet = this.http.get<Task>(url);
  // console.log (returnGet);

  return returnGet
  .pipe(
        map(tasks => tasks[0]), // returns a {0|1} element array
        tap(h => {
          const outcome = h ? `fetched` : `did not find`;
          this.log(`${outcome} hero id=${id}`);
        }),    
    catchError(this.handleError<Task>(`getTask id=${id}`))
  );
}
```

**Create task in the service.ts**

```
addTask (task: Task): Observable<Task> {
  const url = `${this.mainUrl}/entity/node`;
  return this.http.post<Task>(url, task, httpOptions).pipe(
    tap((task: Task) => this.log(`added task w/ id=${task.id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<Task>('addtask'))
  );
}
```

Comment: If you create content by means of a POST request, the created content should be contained in the response of your backend. Using that response would be the normal way to render the new content. The other approach would be to get the elements pushed from the backend into the client by means of a socket

Comment: you can load again the data or update the array (or whatever used)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Yes I can render the content from the backend, with the get method I can see the content, but it doesn't update immediately i need to press F5. I will look for some example of sockets.

Comment: @Eliseo how? can you please give me an example?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @georgeawg done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using the tour of heroes's example, but I hope can help you. Ussually we have an inferface, a service and a component

```
//An interface with the structure of the data
interface IData {
    prop1:number
    prop2:string;
}

//A service 
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    urlBase:string=".....";
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getData(): Observable<IData[]> {
       return this.http.get<IData[]>(urlBase, { params: params });
    }

    postData(data:Idata):Observable<any>{
        return this.http.post<IData>(urlBase,data);
    }

//Your component
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   lista:IData[];   //<--the data we display in our template
   private subscription: Subscription;  //<--a variable to save a subscription

   constructor(private dataService:DataService){}
   ngOnInit()
   {
      fillData(); //<--cal a function to fill this.lista  

   }
   fillData()
   {
       if (this.subscription)   //<--if exist a subscription, remove
           this.subscription.unsubscribe();

       subscription=this.dataService.getData().subscribe((data:IData[])=>
            {this.lista=data;});
    }

   ....
   //In your submit
   submit(form:any)
   {
       if (form.isValid)
       {
            let data=form.value; //<--normally here transform de data from form
                                 //in a object type IData
            this.dataService.postData(data).subscribe(result:any)
            {
                 //here you choose
                 this.lista.push(data)  //<--you add manually the data
                 //or call fillData()
                 this.fillData();
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Very detailed! Thanks a lot... Can you upvote my question, please??